# Two partitions with the same letter from previous install

Tags: partitioning, partition-recovery

I recently recovered Windows from the Recovery partition and since then I am stuck in a very weird situation. First off, my computer tries to boot off of the previous partition which no longer works. Also, I am receiving 2 different partitions with the same drive letters and my total disk size is 226GB instead of 512GB (471GB) as it was in the previous install.

How can I remove the previous partition

For picture 2 I always have to press f9 to boot into Windows.

[image][image]

Comment: You can probably delete the old partition with the bootable CD of Partition Wizard ==> http://www.partitionwizard.com/partition-wizard-bootable-cd.html. But it is not obvious what is going to happen then. Is this an Asus PC ?

Comment: @whs No, it is a Razer Blade